# How to add thermal model on SOAtherm-Nmos block in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, switching-losses

I would like to analyze the junction temperature of a SCT3022AL MOSFET during switching operation on LTspice.

Followint the Spice model and the thermal model of the MOSFET:

https://www.rohm.com/products/sic-power-devices/sic-mosfet/sct3022al-product/documents

I'm going to use SOAtherm-Nmos block.

Unfortunately the thermal model of SCT3022AL is not alredy inserted inside the block.

How can I add the thermal model given in the above link into this block?

Thank You.

Comment: Will you be modeling the junction heating (perhaps 10 microns thick, or about 1.14 microsecond thermal timeconstant) ? Or the silicon thickness (perhaps 100 microns thick, which will be 100X slower, at 114 microsecond thermal timeconstant) ? Or will you include the metal tab that puills out the heat, about 2 milliMeters thick, with 44 millisecond thermal timeconstant? Or do you want to include **all** of those?

Comment: I would like to include all of those if is it possible? Can you explain me better?